# error : word automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, office-automation, word-automation

I have IIS7(Windows Server 2008) 64bit but my application is running in 32bit mode. Ms Office 2003 is installed on server. I cannot find {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} in Component Services but I can see {00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} and I assigned all permissions for it too.

If I apply impersonation then I see winword.exe*32 in task manager and page in progress for long long time just like stick, no response/ error. I noticed that page goes   stick/always in progress with

> **'' Passed and no error with impersonation**

```
Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
```

> **'' Passed and no error with impersonation**

```
Dim objDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
```

> **'' With impersonation, this line of code stick page to long process - Documents.Open**

```
objDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(path)
```

What I am missing? Same code was working with Windows Server 2003 64 bit.

Comment: The advice is don't use Office automation in a service. You're lucky if this is the only error you've seen. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-automation+asp.net

Answer (score 3):

Office Interop is not designed for sever side use. Microsoft has a [Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) article on the topic of server-side automation of Office, you may want to read though it.

Without knowing what you are trying to use the interop for, all I can recommend is switch to using [Office OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) for your sever automation. If you are just doing document manipulation it should allow you to do that. For anything else I would recommend looking over the suggestions for alterintives in the KB article I linked.

---

If you really must there is [a hack solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/545dd81f-e80a-48b0-89a1-dafcd72e269d) to your problem

if you create the folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop` and `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` it may solve your problem, but if you can I would ***highly*** recommend using OpenXML instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have to read .doc (Word 2003) document using programming which is not OpenXML therefore I have to stuck with interop/automation. I have already created Desktop  folder under C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\ and C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\